# Is there a Node.js equivalent to PHP's include, so that included code has access to the parent file's variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I'd like to split my Node app into several separate files to make it more modular and easier to maintain.

But since there is no way to 'include' a file directly into the currently parsed file like in other languages like PHP, my 'modules' or 'separate files' do not automatically get access to the variables defined in the script that 'requires' them.

How can I do this?

I was thinking about doing something like this in my separate files:

```
module.exports = function(stuff) {
  //I now have access to 'stuff'.
}
```

But it's slightly cumbersome.

I'm sure someone has already tackled this before me so... what do you suggest?

Comment: Read the docs: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.5/api/modules.html Using the `exports` object within a module allows you to make certain variables or functions public while other variables remain private. It's quite nice.

Comment: "my 'modules' or 'separate files' do not automatically get access to the variables defined in the script that 'requires' them" - wouldn't that make your code *harder* to maintain? The idea of require.js modules is that they provide functionality to be used by other scripts; if they want access to other modules' public data/method, they should require those modules themselves.

Comment: Consider 'middleware' pattern and remember - your module is in reality just an object with list of functions 'exports' that have been executed during first `require`.

Comment: Passing data around as arguments to function calls makes things much easier in the long run that PHP's default approach of "I'm a template! Let's use globals everywhere!".

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The alternative is to define all my stuff in my main JS file, in which case it will get huge. I understand the idea of a 'module' but in this case I don't want a 'module' I want to simply seperate my logic into files. Many of them need access to my socket.io sockets variable and sequelize etc.

Comment: @PetterThowsen: Ah, yes I see. I haven't done enough with Node.js to know what the intended approach is.

Comment: I think we've defined the socket.io object globally so numerous files can see it. But, isolated modules should use the module system. You most likely want to us `exports.NAME` instead of `module.exports` as the latter replaces the entire export object. Here is a wonderful example: https://gist.github.com/fwielstra/1025038

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to share variables across modules is to assign the variables to the global namespace object. Variables declared how they would be globally declared in a browser are still module-specific in Node, so there is a `global` object.

Using the global scope is considered bad practice, but can be much simpler than other approaches:

**foo.js**

```
global.num = 3;
global.str = 'a string';
require('./bar');
```

**bar.js**

```
console.log(num);  // 3
console.log(str);  // a string
```

Comment: This is incredibly bad practice. It's fine for quick, dirty testing or natural singletons (we keep our logger global, for example). The proper way is to use `module.exports` or `exports.NAME`.

Comment: That is not what the question is asking for, and I already stated in the answer that it was bad practice. The question is looking for a simple way to pass variables from a main script to a module without assigning a function to `module.exports`. Also, I'm not exporting values from a module to its parent, I'm passing variables from the parent to the module.

Comment: I was reaffirming your admission of bad practice, that was certainly unclear from my comment. But, while it does solve the problem, should we promote bad practices?

Comment: In my opinion, giving information with a disclaimer is fine. It is up to the person who asked the question whether they want to use a method or not, which is why this site allows them to choose their answer.